# How to tell if an index has OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY turned on?

Tags: index, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019

SQL Server 2019 brings the `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` option that, as far as I know you specify on index creation or alter using the `WITH` keyword.

But how do you check if the option is already turned on for a given index?

And is it on by default in Server 2019? Or Azure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system view [sys.indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql) has a `bit` column named `optimize_for_sequential_key`.

It is not on by default because it is intended for use only where significant last-page contention is observed.

See [Implementation and contraindications for OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241745/implementation-and-contraindications-for-optimize-for-sequential-key) for more details.